# How to make a basic tagcloud in Bolt

Tags: bolt-cms

Old-fashioned tagcloud-question:

I know how to show the tags used in the current record - but what is the proper way to show a basic tagcloud with all tags that are used within the site?

Answer (score 2):

There is the [Tag Cloud](https://github.com/axsy/bolt-extension-tagcloud) extension by Aleksey Orlov.  From distant memory that provides an unstyled tag cloud, so I think you need to add your own CSS but it worked in my testing!

Comment: Brilliant, looks good. The 'technical' name (that goes into the global config.yml) is TagCloud , right? I could not find that in the docs.

Comment: OK, this is the part I forgot.  In Bolt 1.x, the name you put into extensions[] in config.yml is the name of the directory the extension's files are in.

So if you download those files from Aleksey's repo and put them into a directory called TagCloud, then yes add 'TagCloud' to the config.yml